# Definition of finitely presented $R$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

I found in books two different definitions of a finitely presented $R$-module (with $R$ is a commutative ring).

$*$ the $1$st is :

We say $M$ is a finitely presented $R$-module if there exist  an exact sequence
$$F_0⟶ F_1 ⟶ M ⟶ 0 $$
such that $F_0$ and $F_1$  are free $R$-modules.

$*$ the $2$nd is :

We say $M$ is a finitely presented $R$-module if there exist  an exact sequence 
$$F_0⟶ F_1 ⟶ M ⟶ 0 $$
such that $F_0$ is a finitely generated $R$-module and $F_1$ is a free $R$-module.

Are these two definitions equivalent?

Comment: Neither one is correct, because neither one mentions the requirement that $F_1$ be finitely generated.

Comment: In almost every case when you say "i read some stuff somewhere" you should immediately include the reference for the work. It keeps the conversation relevant, and prevents everyone from going their own directions interpreting "the stuff you read somewhere."

Answer (score 1):

If you replace everywhere ‘free’ by ‘free and finitely generated’ then it becomes correct, and does not require $R$ to be commutative.

A module $M$ is finitely generated precisely when there exists an epimorphism $R^n\twoheadrightarrow M$ for some positive integer $n$. We say that $M$ is finitely presented if moreover the kernel of any such map is again finitely generated.